# Reporting progress of a LINQ query with background worker, how?

Tags: c#, linq, backgroundworker

I am exprementing an application which prints out all the possible multiplies of integers in an array that equals size of the array:

```
private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int progress = 0;

    int toCheck = int.Parse(textBox2.Text); //Number to check for
    int[] array = new int[toCheck];

    //Fill the array
    for (int i = 0; i < toCheck; i++) 
    {
        array[i] = i;
        bgw.ReportProgress(progress);
        progress += 1;
    }

    var result =
        from i1 in array
        from i2 in array
        where i1 * i2 == toCheck
        let square = i1 * i2
        select new { i1, i2, square }; //how to report progress here?

    foreach (var res in result)
    {
        textBox1.Text += res.i1 + " * " + res.i2 + " = " + res.square + Environment.NewLine;

        bgw.ReportProgress(progress);
        progress += 1;
    } 
}
```

The linq query itself is very time consuming specially if a big number should be checked for. Is there a way to report the progress of the linq query? Or I should leave linq and do this old-school mode?

**Update**
This is my whole code. The progressbard does not fill after it got half-full. The first half is when the array is being created, the second part is when code tries to perform the linq query (That is why I think the reporting should be done in the linq query!) pardon my stupidity!!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace BGWorkerTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
        private PerformanceCounter ramCounter;
        string[] diagnosticInfo = new string[2] { string.Empty, string.Empty };

        int toCheck = 0;

        StringBuilder sb;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Diagnostics
            cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();

            cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
            cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
            cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

            ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available KBytes");
        }


        private string[] GetDiagnostics()
        {
            diagnosticInfo[0] = string.Format("{0:0.##}", cpuCounter.NextValue()) + "%";
            diagnosticInfo[1] = ramCounter.NextValue() + "MB";

            return diagnosticInfo;
        }

        private void timerStStr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] temp = new string[2] { "", ""};
            temp = GetDiagnostics();
            ststrLabelCpu.Text = temp[0];
            ststrLabelMem.Text = temp[1];
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ststrProgBar.Minimum = 0;
            ststrProgBar.Maximum = 0;

            toCheck = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

            ststrProgBar.Minimum = 0;
            ststrProgBar.Maximum = toCheck * 2;
            ststrProgBar.Step = 1;

            //Starts the backgroundworker process asynchronously
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync();           
        }

        private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int progress = 0;

            int[] array = new int[toCheck + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < toCheck + 1; i++)
            {
                array[i] = i;
                bgw.ReportProgress(progress);
                progress += 1;
            }

            var result =
                from i1 in array
                from i2 in array
                where i1 * i2 == toCheck
                let square = i1 * i2
                select new { i1, i2, square };

            sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var res in result)
            {
               sb.AppendLine(res.i1 + " * " + res.i2 + " = " + res.square);

               bgw.ReportProgress(progress);
               progress += 1;

               Application.DoEvents();
            } 
        }

        private void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ststrProgBar.PerformStep();
        }

        private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Operation Cancelled");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Operation Completed");

                textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're alraedy reporting progress every time you find a match; do you want to report progress every time you find a non-match too?

Comment: I don't understand, where I have reported the finding of a match in the linq query I wrote?! the `ReportProgress()` in the for loop is just to report array is being created, since larger ints take quite a while for the array to be filled up. And for the text box is reporting everytime a line is going to be added. I dont have report inside the actual linq query.

Comment: Linq is lazy; it doesn't find every match and then pass them to your foreach loop, but passes the values to your foreach loop one by one as soon as each is found. Thus your ReportProgress in the foreach loop should essentially be reporting every time a match is found. If that's not happening - e.g. you get a massive wait, followed by lots of quick reports - I'm not sure why.

Comment: Do you mean that the `result` is being created and added to each time foreach refers to it?

Comment: So how about when it does not find a match?

Comment: If you want it to report every combination that doesn't work... I'll try to write one as an answer.

Comment: Related: [How can I report progress from a PLINQ query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55584078/how-can-i-report-progress-from-a-plinq-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result =      
    from int i1 in array      
    from int i2 in array      
    where i1 * i2 == toCheck      
    let square = getSquare(i1,i2)      
    select new { i1, i2, square };
```

And then create the method:

```
 public static int getSquare(int i, int i2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("busy {0}", i);
        return i * i2;
    }
```

just change `Console.WriteLine("busy {0}", i);` to whatever you want to report

Comment: Can you please explain the inheritence in the first code you worte? I really dont have lots of info about classes :P

Comment: ok, so I changed it because that would have outputted when the linq query was executed but before the output was created.

Comment: You need to also report the progress. You could do that inside getSquare, by e.g. firing an event.

Comment: thx, whole reason for the getSquare method, just forgot the progress but added it later :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> ActAsEnumerated<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> act)
{
    foreach(var t in source)
    {
        act(t);
        yield return t;
    }
}
```

Usage could be something like:

```
var pairs = from i1 in array from i2 in array select new { int1 = i1, int2 = i2 };
var reportPairs = pairs.ActAsEnumerated(p => { bgw.ReportProgress(progress); progress += 1; });

var result =
    from pair in reportPairs
    where pair.int1 * pair.int2 == toCheck
    let square = pair.int1 * pair.int2
    select new { pair.int1, pair.int2, square };
```

which is really not very pretty. Really, I think you'd be better off doing this in a non-Linq fashion.

Comment: This operator exists in the [System.Interactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive/) package with the name [`Do`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive/System/Linq/Operators/Do.cs).